# How to get access to a service provider after creating and running the default host?

Tags: c#, .net-core

I have a .NET Core console application and create a new default host instance. I'm configuring my services in a static extensions class and there is one service that is a singleton. In my `Program` file I have to get access to the instance once so I can call a method from it.

Given this sample code

```
class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
        => new Program()
            .MainAsync(args)
            .GetAwaiter()
            .GetResult();

    private async Task MainAsync(string[] args)
    {
        await Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureServices((hostBuilderContext, serviceCollection) =>
            {
                // This comes from another class configuring all the services for the serviceCollection
                serviceCollection.AddSingleton<MyService>();
            })
            .Build()
            .RunAsync();
        
        // Get access to the service provider
        // Get MyService instance from the service provider
    }
}
```

Is there a way to create a new instance of a service provider on the fly below the method `RunAsync`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Host.CreateDefaultBuilder` returns `IHostBuilder` which provides `IHostBuilder.Build` which in turn returns `IHost`. `IHost` contains property  `IHost.Services` representing configured DI container. In case you want to access it, store `IHost` inside a variable before starting it.

```
    private async Task MainAsync(string[] args)
    {
        var host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureServices((hostBuilderContext, serviceCollection) =>
            {
                // This comes from another class configuring all the services for the serviceCollection
                serviceCollection.AddSingleton<MyService>();
            })
            .Build();

        await host.StartAsync();
        var myService = host.Services.GetRequiredService<MyService>();
        /* some useful code */

        await host.WaitForShutdownAsync();
    }
```